# Windows partion not showing in virtual Ubuntu 16.0

Tags: windows-7, filesystem

I have installed virtual Ubuntu 16.0 in windows 7 machine.
Linux system not showing windows partition.

Windows partition is shown in `gparted` partition software .

Below is my file system details.

---

```
sudo parted -l
Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 54.3GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  53.2GB  53.2GB  primary   ext4            boot
 2      53.2GB  54.3GB  1072MB  extended
 5      53.2GB  54.3GB  1072MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


hitesh@hitesh-VirtualBox:~$ sudo fdisk -lu
Disk /dev/sda: 50.6 GiB, 54268166144 bytes, 105992512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf75dafc7

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 103897087 103895040 49.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       103899134 105992191   2093058 1022M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       103899136 105992191   2093056 1022M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

---

How can I show windows partition in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

You are using virtual box (as this line indicates: `Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)`). Virtual machine isolates host machine (Windows 7 in your case) from guest machine (Ubuntu in your case); this means that you can't see the hard disk of Windows 7 from Ubuntu.

If you want to share some files between these machines you can use VirtualBox sharing system or other network based file sharing like: SMB, FTP, SSHFS, ...

Comment: thanks for reply, can u guide me for using VirtualBox sharing system or other network based file sharing like: SMB, FTP, SSHFS, ...

Comment: @Hitesh: IMO the best way is SSH. SSH is a nice protocol which allow file transfer (beside its main job i.e remote shell access). Make your Ubuntu as SSH Server (See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) ). Next install and use WinSCP (Donwload [here](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)). Connect to your Ubuntu VM using WinSCP then you can transfer any file between them using its explorer window,